# Content size of UITextView not changing after wrapping around exclusion path

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` with a `UIImageView` over top of it. I have the text view wrapping its text around the image like so (in the view controller):

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let imageBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: imageRect)
    overviewTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [imageBezierPath]
}
```

This is working fine to wrap the text, but here's the problem: I have the text view (lorem ipsum below) in a `UIStackView` with scrolling disabled, and I have items beneath it ("Label below"). I'd like its height to expand as it wraps, but it's not. I printed the text view's `contentSize.height` before and after setting the `exclusionPaths` property, but see no change.

[image: Text that wraps, but doesn't continue]

You can see at the bottom of the lorem ipsum where I put some English to make it easier to tell that the text view is truncated.

Is this expected behavior for `UITextView`? What can I do to either update the `contentSize`, or manually calculate how much space the text now takes up?

**Update**

With some help from @DonMag, I made a playground to reproduce the issue. As you tap the button to toggle the exclusion path, the text doesn't wrap the way it should.

https://gist.github.com/abbeycode/b40ade1f23a8946a12ad816e1bc0f2b1

Comment: Hmmm... seems to work fine for me. Here is an example you can put in a Playground page: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/e79e40f23fd034921cbdbbca2e584b49 ... if you tap the button, it will print the `.contentSize` of the text view. Changing the height of the `imageRect` (line 32 in the code) appears to properly change the wrapping and the `.contentSize`.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks, that's super helpful. It looks like my problem must have something to do with the constraints I've set up (or it being inside a Stack View inside a Scroll View). I'll figure out better where it's going wrong and update the question when I know more.

Comment: @DonMag I think it might be because I used Interface Builder, and the playground sets up the constraints in `viewDidLoad`. Try my modified playground: https://gist.github.com/abbeycode/b40ade1f23a8946a12ad816e1bc0f2b1 … tapping the button toggles the wrapping and I see the same behavior. I try forcing a re-layout, and it doesn't help

Comment: Dov - seems odd. It appears the text view is not getting a "you need to change something" message when you set the `exclusionPaths`. Don't know if that's a bug, or if I just don't know the right thing to call. Here is a workaround if you want - it's your exact gist, I just added a couple lines to "clear and replace text" after you change the `exclusionPaths` - seems to work: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/a97de9749f5915615e8a286aac5e3ec4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is a bug, or "standard" behavior, or if there is a "force update" command that I'm not aware of, but...

Here is a workaround to get the text view to recalculate its contentSize. When changing the `.exclusionPaths` you can clear-and-replace the text:

```
@objc
func didTap(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {

    if overviewTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths.first != nil {
        overviewTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = []
    } else {
        let imageBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: imageRect)
        overviewTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [imageBezierPath]
    }

    let s = overviewTextView.text
    overviewTextView.text = " "
    overviewTextView.text = s

}
```

A Playground runnable full version is here: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/a97de9749f5915615e8a286aac5e3ec4

Comment: Thanks! I submitted a radar for this: rdar://36330838

Comment: If the user is editing while using this method you may want to save and reset `selectedTextRange` as well.